# Spring Webflow: How to to customize externalRedirect in end-state?

Tags: spring-webflow-2

The parent flow of my webflows has the following end-state defined:

```
<end-state id="endState" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:index.html"/>
```

This will redirect to `http://server/context/index.html`

All my flows are now configured to run in an "embedded" mode (no menus/header/etc.) if the context path contains `/embedded` (I implemented this by using my own `ViewResolver` and different tiles layouts). Example: `http://server/context/embedded/page.htm` uses the same flow as `http://server/context/page.htm` but with a different layout.

When the site is running in "embedded" mode I want the end-state to redirect to `http://server/context/embedded/index.html`.

How can I customize this to rather use `externalRedirect:contextRelative:embedded/index.html` when the the URI contains `/embedded`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could determine the embedded state from a managed bean and use EL to determine a path:

```
externalRedirect:contextRelative:#{myBean.getPath()}
```